# Spring Tool Suite ignores @GetMapping @PostMapping

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

It seems to be, that Spring Tool Suite 3.8.3 ignores the newer MVC mapping annotations @GetMapping, @PostMapping etc. on creating the request mapping view. If a @RestController annotated class uses @RequestMapping only, all handler methods are shown in both Spring Tools => Show RequestMappings and Spring Explorer => Beans => Request Mapping. But if only the @RestController annotated class uses @RequestMapping and all handler methods uses @GetMapping, @PostMapping or @DeleteMapping, then those handler method mapping are not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Boot Dashboard can show these request mapping if app is running. However, there is no support probably to show these in `Request Mappings` view based on annotations scanning. Feel free to raise this issue via Spring-IDE GitHub page: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues

Comment: you should note, that the actuator 'mappping' endpoint must be enabled for showing these infos in Boot Dashboard.

Comment: After enabling (all) actuators and double check with http request ```<myApp>/mappings``` within the browser .... but the RequestMappings tab in the Boot dashboard properties view still remains empty....

Comment: It's not the Request Mapping view you should be looking to find your request mappings with Boot Dashboard. Right-Click on your running app in Boot Dashboard, then click on Show Properties menu item. Properties view for the app would open. Click on the Request Mappings tab in the properties view.

Comment: ... but this tab is empty. I've opened an issue at github https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/101

Comment: Does the tab state that you had to add an `actuator` dependency to see something? Right-click on your `pom.xml` click of on `Edit Starters` and find `Actuator` dependency (under Ops), add it then restart your app and check the tab again.